# How to make a query across multiple models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset, relationship

I'm using Django and I want to know how to get objects through 3 models
These are my models

```py
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="participants")
    application_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    resolution_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="")
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='teams')
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='teams')

class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    initial_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    qr_step_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image_resolution = models.IntegerField(default=800)
    sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Sponsor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='campaigns')
```

I have the user through a request, and I want to get all campaigns of that user.
I tried doing it with for loops but I want to do it with queries
this is what I had:

```py
user = request.user
participants = user.participant_set.all()
for participant in participants:
  participant.team.campaign.name
```

is there a way to make a query through these models and for all participants?
A user can have many participants, and each participant has a Team, each team has a campaign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel W. Steinbrook to guide me to the answer, I had to do this to get the query:

```py
Campaign.objects.filter(teams__participants__user__exact=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to merge the two modela `Team` and `Campaign` in one model.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this should work:

```
Campaign.objects.filter(team__participant__user=request.user)
```

The Django ORM is smart enough to follow foreign key relationships in both directions.

Comment: Thank you! it finally was this ```Campaign.objects.filter(teams__participants__user__exact=request.user)```